# best way to store configurations

Tags: xml, database, json, configuration, resource-management

I'm implementing a configuration manager with full API, similar to the Windows registry.
I want it to be human readable, as in being able to open and edit it with a text editor.
I want it to be able to store any type of configuration information that a program could possibly need, as well as be fast enough to be useful.

I've looked at the following markup languages for storing the information:

- XML
- JSON
- YAML
- S-expression

But I am not sure what language would be proper for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is very late but I would suggest you use **YAML**. Very human readable and it is widely used for configurations and would meet your needs "***I want it to be able to store any type of configuration information that a program could possibly need***". The only downside to it is the indentation style that uses space, you have to be very careful because wrong indentation means a different interpretation of the content. Once you get used to it, it's very easy to use.